# Mongodb: how to compare DB to new data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Each week I receive a new copy of source data (8500, and growing, records approx and with an id field that Mongo uses as `_id`) and I want to look for (and save, while keeping the old data) updated information (about 30 changes/additions per month are likely). I'm trying to work out the best approach.

My first thought was, for each entry in new data, get the DB entry with that _id, compare, and update the data where changed. But that results in 8500 asynchronous calls over the net (to mongolab) + 30 `upserts` where new/changed data needs to be saved.

So, the alternative is to download everything at the outset. But then I end up with an Array from Mongo and would need to do `Array.find` each time to get the element that matches with the new data.

**Is there a Mongo command to return the results of `.find({})` as a Javascript Object keyed by _id?** Or, does it otherwise make sense to take the raw array form Mongo and covert it myself to an object

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here. Are you trying to work out what you already have to avoid asking for that from an external source? Or are you just trying to not create new entries when something already exists in your data store? Examples speak a bit louder than words in explaining what you are doing.

Comment: Couldn't you make use of mongo upsert? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#upsert-option

Comment: I do use that as the new data can also contain entirely new documents (with a new id), but the question is about how to keep versions of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will store : 
id + version + date + datas

For each update :

1. Make a dump of prod DB for local usage
2. work offline, in a local mongoDB  (because  you don't want to launch 9000 query over the web)
3. for each line
    compare datas to mongo datas
    if modifications ==true, will store a new/first (id+version)
   else skip;
4. make a dump of  your local DB
5. installl dump to  production environnement

[mongodb doc dump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: thanks. I'm going to re-ask the question about data structure as that's the but I am now stuck on